# How to separate site side and the admin panel side within one project (nuxt.js)?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a small project whose frontend I would like to develop on nuxt.js. It is a very convenient and simple framework.

But I have the problem of separating the application into two parts: site side and admin panel side.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Site:
- components
- layouts
- pages
- store
nuxt.config.js

Admin:
- components
- layouts
- pages
- store
nuxt.config.js

static
middleware
utilities
plugins
```

But nuxt.js in every possible way does not allow to do so. I really feel that I do something wrong.

I saw a huge number of questions about this on the Internet, but without answers.

Perhaps the time has come and someone will be able to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a monorepo approach:

> Monorepos let you develop multiple packages in the same repository, which is fantastic for productivity. You can share code, establish clear ownership, and have fast unified CI. That is why more and more teams are switching to this way of development.

Check the [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) documentation.

I have seen this approach to have both frontend and backend projects in the same folder structure (then also in the same git repository), perhaps it will work with two nuxt projects (one for the site, another for the admin...and they both could share some code as well).

Comment: I recommend [nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) rather.